# Suppress month and day for journal articles and maintain for a newspaper articles

Tags: biblatex, conditionals

I haven't found a solution yet for this problem. I want to suppress month and day (if present) from all journal articles in bibliography but I at the same time I want to indicate year, month and day for newspaper or magazine article.

This is complicated by the fact that journal and newspaper articles are all labelled as `@article` in bibtex. A possible solution would be to remove month and day selectively only IF the `@article` entry contains one or both of the fields `volume` or `number` (thus assuming that it is in fact a journal article).

I though about something like this, but my TeX is not that good...

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
% AND IF entry contains {number} and/or {volume}
    \clearfield{month}%
    \clearfield{day}%
  }{%
  }%
}
```

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
  @article{test1,
    title = {Ideas \& trends; politics of the web: {Meet}, greet, segregate, meet again},
    url = {http://www.nytimes.com/2004/01/25/weekinreview/ideas-trends-politics-of-the-web-meet-greet-segregate-meet-again.html},
    urldate = {2014-01-14},
    journal = {New {York} {Times}},
    author = {Harmon, Amy},
    day = {01},
    month = jan,
    year = {2004},
  }
  @article{test2,
    title = {Social movement networks virtual and real},
    volume = {3},
    issn = {1369-118X},
    url = {http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13691180051033333},
    doi = {10.1080/13691180051033333},
    number = {3},
    urldate = {2013-05-31},
    journal = {Information, {Communication} \& {Society}},
    author = {Diani, Mario},
    month = jan,
    year = {2000},
    pages = {386--401}
  }
}
\end{filecontents*}

% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
style=apa,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{test1}

\cite{test2}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `entrysubtype` instead of this guessing conditional (newspaper articles could have `entrysubtype = {newspaper}`, you could filter those very easily).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic conditional can be built using [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\ifboolexpr` (`etoolbox` is loaded by `biblatex`; see also the [`etoolbox` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) and the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), esp. §4.6.3 *Tests with `\ifboolexpr` and `\ifthenelse`*, pp. 179 sq.).

In an `\ifboolexpr` we can use all the test provided by `biblatex` (see §4.6.2 *Stand-alone Tests*, p. 171-179 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)): we just add a `test` before the test and wrap the command in curly braces, we also omit the "true" and "false" branch.
So `\iffieldundef{volume}{true}{false}` becomes `\ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{volume}}}{true}{false}`; the beauty of `\ifboolexpr` is that we can use logical operator to connect expressions.

In the case at hand, we then have

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{article}} and (not test {\iffieldundef{number}} or not test {\iffieldundef{volume}})}
    {\clearfield{month}%
     \clearfield{day}}
     {}%
}
```

this deletes the `month` and `day` fields for `@articles` that have a `number` or `volume` field (or both, as the `or` is the logical inclusive or).

---

You could also make use of the `entrysubtype` field, just add `entrysubtype = {newspaper}` to every `@article` entry that is from a newspaper (surprise, surprise).

```
@article{test1,
  title         = {Ideas \& trends; politics of the web: {Meet}, greet, segregate, meet again},
  url           = {http://www.nytimes.com/2004/01/25/weekinreview/ideas-trends-politics-of-the-web-meet-greet-segregate-meet-again.html},
  urldate       = {2014-01-14},
  journal       = {New {York} {Times}},
  author        = {Harmon, Amy},
  day           = {01},
  month         = jan,
  year          = {2004},
  entrysubtype  = {newspaper},%<---- here it is
}
```

We then use the conditional

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{article}} and not test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{newspaper}}}
    {\clearfield{month}%
     \clearfield{day}}
    {}%
}
```

to delete `month` and `day` from `@articles` that are not `newspaper` `@articles`.

---

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test1,
  title         = {Ideas \& trends; politics of the web: {Meet}, greet, segregate, meet again},
  url           = {http://www.nytimes.com/2004/01/25/weekinreview/ideas-trends-politics-of-the-web-meet-greet-segregate-meet-again.html},
  urldate       = {2014-01-14},
  journal       = {New {York} {Times}},
  author        = {Harmon, Amy},
  day           = {01},
  month         = jan,
  year          = {2004},
  %entrysubtype  = {newspaper},
}
@article{test2,
  title     = {Social movement networks virtual and real},
  volume    = {3},
  issn      = {1369-118X},
  url       = {http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13691180051033333},
  doi       = {10.1080/13691180051033333},
  number    = {3},
  urldate   = {2013-05-31},
  journal   = {Information, {Communication} \& {Society}},
  author    = {Diani, Mario},
  month     = jan,
  year      = {2000},
  pages     = {386--401},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
  style=apa,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{article}} and (not test {\iffieldundef{number}} or not test {\iffieldundef{volume}})}
  %\ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{article}} and not test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{newspaper}}}
    {\clearfield{month}%
     \clearfield{day}}
    {}%
}

\begin{document}
  Lorem \parencite{test1} ipsum \parencite{test2}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, this is surprisingly simple, yet could be adapted for many situations.

Comment: @doncherry Yes, `\ifboolexpr` really is an awesome tool together with all the tests `biblatex` offers.

Answer (score 1):

The new [Bibulous project](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/) provides an alternative solution for what the OP asks for. Although Bibulous can check for the presence of a field that acts as a flag (in the BibLatex solution provided by @moewe, using the `entrysubtype` field), a cleaner solution for Bibulous is to simply define a new entrytype for newspaper articles that differentiate them from journal articles. Thus, using the following database file `main.bib`

```
@newsarticle{test1,
  title = {Ideas \& trends; politics of the web: {Meet}, greet, segregate, meet again},
  url = {http://www.nytimes.com/2004/01/25/weekinreview/ideas-trends-politics-of-the-web-meet-greet-segregate-meet-again.html},
  urldate = {2014-01-14},
  journal = {New York Times},
  author = {Harmon, Amy},
  day = {1},
  month = jan,
  year = {2004}
}

@article{test2,
  title = {Social movement networks virtual and real},
  volume = {3},
  issn = {1369-118X},
  url = {http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13691180051033333},
  doi = {10.1080/13691180051033333},
  number = {3},
  urldate = {2013-05-31},
  journal = {Information, Communication \& Society},
  author = {Diani, Mario},
  month = jan,
  year = {2000},
  pages = {386--401}
}
```

we can develop a Bibulous-format style file `main.bst` such as

```
TEMPLATES:
article = <au> (<year>). <title>. \textit{<journal>} \textit{<volume>}(<number>),{ }...
          [<startpage>--<endpage>|<startpage>|<eid>|].[ doi:\url{<doi>}| url:\url{<url>}]
newsarticle = <au> (<year>, <month.monthname()> <day>). <title>.{ }...
          \textit{<journal>}. Retrieved <urldate>, from \url{<url>}.

SPECIAL-TEMPLATES:
authorlist = <author.to_namelist()>
editorlist = <editor.to_namelist()>
au = <authorlist.format_authorlist()>
ed = <editorlist.format_editorlist()>
citelabel = (<authorlist.0.last>, <year>)

OPTIONS:
namelist_format = last_name_first
```

(The above block shows the entire style file.) Finally, we need to redefine the `\@biblabel` and `\@cite` macros to make Latex use the correct citation labels in the text. Thus, the `main.tex` file will look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper, text={6.2in,8.5in},centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=True,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
   \renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{}
   \renewcommand{\@cite}[2]{{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem \cite{test1} ipsum \cite{test2}.

\bibliography{example9}
\bibliographystyle{example9}

\end{document}
```

When compiled, this produces the formatted reference list shown below:

[image: Formatted reference list]