# Suppress url from biblatex newspaper articles exported from Zotero

Tags: biblatex, zotero, better-bibtex

I am using Zotero + Better BibTex and using the biblatex package to generate a bibliography in APA citation style. I want to exclude url and urldate from academic journal @articles but retain them for newspaper @articles. I have been successful in suppressing urls from ALL articles using the code found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172444/suppress-month-and-day-for-journal-articles-and-), but I do not see how to add entrysubtype fields to items in Zotero so that I can exclude urls from academic articles alone. Is there a way to enter entrysubtype in Zotero, or is there some other LaTex hack I can use based on an existing @article field?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: In your Zotero database or in you bib file, what is the difference between an academic journal @article and a newspaper @article?

Comment: The cleanest way would be if Zetoro exported the `entrysubtype` field and you use that in your code. https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/531 mentions the field, but https://github.com/andersjohansson/zotero-biblatex-translator/wiki/Biblatex-fields seems a bit more pessimistic. You need a way to distinguish normal articles from newspaper ones and `entrysubtype` is conceptually the best, if Zotero does not support that currently, maybe ask them nicely.

Comment: @moewe I asked about this at [https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/531](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/531) and they replied with a code snippet that added the entrysubtype for newspaper articles on export: 'if (this.item.itemType === 'newspaperArticle') {
  this.add({ entrysubtype: 'newspaper' });
}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `entrysubtype = {newspaper}` for those `@article`s from a newspaper,

```
@article{frie2002,
  author  = {Jonathan Friedland},
  title   = {Across the Divide},
  journal = {Guardian}, 
  pages   = {10-11},
  date    = {2002-01-15},
  entrysubtype = {newspaper},
  url     = {https://www.theguardian.com/uk},
  urldate = {2016-09-16},
}
```

you only need

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{article}} and not test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{newspaper}}}
    {\clearfield{url}%
     \clearfield{urlyear}}
    {}%
}
```

to delete the `url` and `urldate` for non-newspaper `@article`s.

`biblatex-apa`, however, also has a `@newsarticle` entry type

```
@newsarticle{frie2002,
  author    = {Jonathan Friedland},
  title     = {Across the Divide},
  newspaper = {Guardian}, 
  pages     = {10-11},
  date      = {2002-01-15},
  url       = {https://www.theguardian.com/uk},
  urldate   = {2016-09-16},
}
```

in which case you want

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{newsarticle}
    {\clearfield{url}%
     \clearfield{urlyear}}
    {}%
}
```

Comment: Where exactly has the `\AtEveryBibitem` stuff to be included? in the tex file I suppose, but where exactly? in the preamble? Before `\addbibresource`, after it? somewhere else?

Comment: @helt In the preamble after `biblatex` has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep all the info about your references intact, copy them from Zotero to your document and still be able to remove unnecessary fields in a reference list.

`biblatex` has an option to declare maps, which formats items that appear in the reference. Both groups of types or an individual type can be included in mapping. This is explained in *Dynamic Modification of Data* (see p. 199 of [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)). Personally, I use it for removing urls but I think you can do much more.

In solution below, `URL`'s appear only in online-like reference types, hence I declared the following mapping

```latex
\DeclareSourcemap{%
  \maps{%
    % remove URLs for non-online types
    \map{%
      \pernottype{www}
      \pernottype{online}
      % Do not show urls, eprints, and urldates
      \step[fieldset=url, null]
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
      \step[fieldset=eprint, null]
    }%
  }%
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Observe both the article and the book entries still contain `url`.

---

The full code

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{example.bib}
@article{frie2002,
    author  = {Jonathan Friedland},
    title   = {Across the Divide},
    journal = {Guardian}, 
    pages   = {10-11},
    date    = {2002-01-15},
    entrysubtype = {newspaper},
    url     = {https://www.theguardian.com/uk},
    urldate = {2016-09-16},
}
@book{ref:murphy2012,
  title = {Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective},
  author = {Murphy, Kevin P.},
  date = {2012},
  series = {Adaptive {{Computation}} and {{Machine Learning}} Series},
  publisher = {{The MIT Press}},
  abstract = {A comprehensive introduction to machine learning that uses probabilistic models and inference as a unifying approach.},
  isbn = {978-0-262-01802-9},
  url = {http://www.example.url.address},
  file = {/home/ziko/Documents/research/papers/pdfs/Murphy/2012/murphy_2012_machine learning.pdf}
}
@www{GoogleWWW,
  title        = {Google website},
  author       = {Google},
  url = {https://www.google,com},
  year         = 2022,
  note         = {Accessed:2022-07-23},
}
@online{CitekeyMiscAudio,
  title        = {Audio: The 'Other' Red Planet},
  author       = {NASA},
  url = {https://www.nasa.gov/nh/pluto-the-other-red-planet},
  year         = 2015,
  note         = {Accessed: 2018-12-06},
}
@online{CitekeyMiscVideo,
  title        = {Video: The 'Other' Red Planet},
  author       = {NASA},
  url = {https://www.nasa.gov/nh/pluto-the-other-red-planet},
  year         = 2015,
  note         = {Accessed: 2018-12-06},
}
\end{filecontents*}
%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{example.bib}
    \DeclareSourcemap{%
      \maps{%
        \map{%
          % remove URLs from non-internet types
          \pernottype{www}
          \pernottype{online}
          % Do not show urls, eprints, and urldates
          \step[fieldset=url, null]
          \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
          \step[fieldset=eprint, null]
        }%
      }%
    }
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=References]
\end{document}
```